# recover data from samsung galaxy s4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-recovery, broken-screen

I have samsung galaxy s4 broken touch and display.
 i want to recover data from it such as videos,photos,contacts and whats app chat without pc.

Comment: WhatsApp - usually it's automatically backed up to Google drive, so when you download WhatsApp and use the same number on a new phone, it should give you the backup. Contacts - if you had them backed up to Google they will also come to your new phone as long as you sign in with the same account (see contacts.Google.com). Pic/vid if you had Google phots backup that data you can check www.photos.google.com

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! As this is a frequent question here, we've already collected some information on it. Please start with the data-recovery section in our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) and see if those links help you. Then report back if and how you were able to solve your issue, or what you tried and where you're stuck. Good luck!